# Android gif making

Tags: android, video, animated-gif

I have one problem:

I'm using code on this site: [android-er](http://android-er.blogspot.rs/2014/12/create-animated-gif-from-mp4.html) to make a gif.

Problem: When I make a video and try to convert it to a GIF (Video is 10 sec.) I can get only max. 10 frames from the video. 
When i change this:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i+=10){
  long frameTime = maxDur * i/100;
  bmFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(frameTime);
  animatedGifEncoder.addFrame(bmFrame);
  publishProgress(i);
}
```

to make more frames: `(for i=0;i<100;i+=2)`
It doesn't show me 50 frames. It only show 10 and the rest 40 are coppies of that 10 frames. It only takes key frames, I tried with getFrameAtTime(frameTime, OPTION_CLOSEST) and it was same.
I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

bmFrame = mmRetriever.getFrameAtTime(time*1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);

first param -> μs;
second param -> use OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC

Comment: Hello,
Time is already in μs and I already used every option: OPTION_CLOSEST (_SYNC), OPTION_PREVIOUS(_SYNC), OPTION_NEXT. And it didn't work.
It only showed key frames

Comment: If there are many null pointer exception，this is my code,I hope it is useful： http://www.oschina.net/code/snippet_266004_50774

But I also have a few questions unsolved:

1. The GIF files I need to compress it,
2. Sometimes OOM